# Finding parameter names from anonymous function

Tags: matlab, parameters, anonymous-function

I want to be able to find the parameter names of an anonymous function in Matlab.

I tried to see if there was any information about the parameter names in the functions() command, but to no avail.

Say I have an anonymous function f:

```
f = @(x, y) x^2 + y^2
```

I need to be able to find the parameter names 'x' and 'y' from this equation. Is there a built in method in Matlab which can do this? Or would I somehow have to parse the function to receive the parameter names?

Comment: I do not think there is a built-in function for that. `func2str` converts it to a string from which you should be able to parse the arguments.

Comment: Ah, but this would not be very general as I would have to add many rules to see if a  variable x is a build in Matlab function or if it actually is a parameter. Or, for example, that the parser would not see the s in the function "sin()" as a parameter etc etc.. It seems like too much of a hassle. Thank you anyway!

Also; maybe this should be a requested feature of Matlab, to have more information about the function in the functions() command, such as parameter names?

Comment: Actually, the struct functions(fun) has a field from which I can parse the parameter names from, if I parse the parenthesis after the @. I will try this. The field is: function: '@(x,y)x^2+y^2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `function` field in the output of [`functions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) (or equivalently the output of [`func2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/func2str.html)) gives the function definition as a string. You then use a regular expression to match each sequence of one or more non-`)`, non-`,` characters that are between a `@(` or `,` and a `,` or `)`:

```
s = functions(f);
inputVarNames = regexp(s.function, '(?<=(,|@\())[^\)]+?(?=(,|\)))', 'match');
```

Comment: This is exctly what I was looking for, thank you! However one small problem. If my function has parenthesise inside, this will be included inside the inputVarNames. And adding a  @ before the ( in the regexp expression does not work, it gives me 0 matches.

Comment: I ended up parsing the string until it found the first ), then saving all the characters up until that point in a new string, and passing that new string into the function you mentioned above. This solved the issue, as only the first parenthesise bracket was being analysed. Thanks for the great help!

Comment: Not between two commas? I think the more general solution is to extract the first pair of parenthesis, everything in between is a comma-separates list of arguments.

Comment: @SigfridStjärnholm I have modified the regular expression. This should solve the issue